# Use a CURL to work with sites without api?

Tags: services

I have this problem.
I need to programmatically submit forms on multiple sites and receive data
The sites do not use API
This task perfectly solves the CURL.
Is there a solution to this issue Drupal way?
Maybe https://www.drupal.org/project/services?

Comment: Yes, sounds like you need the Services module.

Comment: Give an example, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Services module provides API endpoints, it doesn't help to make HTTP requests.

All Drupal has natively for making HTTP requests is [`drupal_http_request()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7). Personally I'd recommend using a library like [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) instead, it's much more pleasing to work with, and has [support for submitting forms](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#post-form-requests). Plus it's in core for Drupal 8 so you know it's got the seal of approval.

PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) should be more than enough to help with processing the response.